# Magento 2 : admin product edit page custom attribute with customised Ui-Select

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-select

I have created product attribute with input type `select` below, I have put attribute create code.

```
$eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(Product::ENTITY, 'seller_id', [
            'type'                    => 'int',
            'label'                   => 'Seller',
            'input'                   => 'select',
            'required'                => true,
            'sort_order'              => 1,
            'source'                  => 'Kunj\Seller\Model\Config\Source\Sellers',
            'global'                  => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
            'user_defined'            => true,
            'visible_on_front'        => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'is_used_in_grid'         => true,
            'is_visible_in_grid'      => true,
            'is_filterable_in_grid'   => true,
            'group'                   => 'General'
        ]);
```

Now, everything is working fine with that attribute, I have attached screenshot.

[image]

Now, I want to display without the default option like this.

[image]

And option should appear with ajax and options list should be based on search keyword.

Answer (score 0):

@kunj Could you share here the Kunj\Seller\Model\Config\Source\Sellers file